# Maximum principle of the Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Prove that the following equation $\nabla^2u=f$ where $f>0$ holds the maximum principle and do not hold the minimum principle.

I thought of an example $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ on a circle domain. So its maximum is on the circle while its minimum is not.

But how do i prove this for a general $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $u\in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline \Omega)$. If $u$ attains its maximum at $x_0 \in \Omega$ (i.e. in the interior) then $\nabla^2u(x_0)\leqslant 0$ which contradicts the fact $\nabla^2 u(x_0)=f(x_0) >0$. Hence, $u$ must attain its maximum on the boundary of $\Omega$.

To show that minimum principle doesn’t hold, your counter-example is still fine because you only need to find a counter-example for some $f$ not all $f$.